# Google app engine - Bugs in the code

Tags: python

My code is this:

```
import webapp2
import re
form = """<html>
<form method=post>
<input name="username"><div id=div>%s</div><br>
<input name="password"><div id=div>%s</div><br>
<input name="verify"><div id=div>%s</div><br>
<input name="email"><div id=div>%s</div>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</html>"""
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
      self.response.write(form % ('','','',''))

  def reply(self,user,password,verify,email):
      if not user and password and verify and email:
        self.redirect('/broski')
      else:
        self.response.write(form % (user,password,verify,email))

  def post(self):
      self.usererror = ''
      if not re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$").match(self.request.get('username')):
       self.usererror = "That's not a valid username."
      self.passworderror = ''
      if not re.compile(r"^.{3,20}$").match(self.request.get('password')):
        self.passworderror = "That wasn't a valid password."
      self.verifyerror = ''
      if self.request.get('verify') != self.request.get('password') and self.request.get('password') != '':
        self.verifyerror = "Your passwords didn't match."
      self.emailerror = ''
      if not re.compile(r"^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$").match(self.request.get('email')):
        self.emailerror = "That's not a valid email."
      self.reply(usererror,passworderror,verifyerror,emailerror)

class ThankYo(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      self.response.write('Welcome, ' + self.request.get('username')+'!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),('/broski', ThankYo)],
                              debug=True)
```

It is literally my first time writing a code for GAE(And im new to python..) larger than 10 lines and, ofcourse, he broke.
I found several bugs but to absolutely on help as the website still doesnt even load.
Help regarding the code is highly appreciated. 
Update: I updated it a little bit more(Changed inheritance of ThankYo) and now the form successfully loads, as soon as i post the data ofcourse it crashes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ThankYo(Mainpage):
```

should be

```
class ThankYo(MainPage):
```

(note the capital `P`).

---

I found this by looking at the error messages left in the terminal:

```
% dev_appser  File "/home/unutbu/pysrc/project/main.py", line 38, in <module>
...
    class ThankYo(Mainpage):   
NameError: name 'Mainpage' is not defined
```

---

Also change

```
self.reply(usererror,passworderror,verifyerror,emailerror)
```

to

```
self.reply(self.usererror, self.passworderror, self.verifyerror, self.emailerror)
```

---

I found this again by looking at the terminal error message:

```
  File "/home/unutbu/pysrc/project/main.py", line 39, in post
    self.reply(usererror, passworderror, verifyerror, emailerror)
NameError: global name 'usererror' is not defined
```

---

**How to see error messages (from the terminal):**

There is more than one way to start the GAE server. The way I do it is by opening a terminal and running

```
dev_appserver.py /path/to/project/
```

The terminal then spews useful error messages.

---

The last problem is a bit more complex. We are sending error messages to the `reply` method:

```
self.reply(self.usererror, self.passworderror, self.verifyerror, self.emailerror)
```

But in the `reply` method definition we call them `user`, `password`, `verify` and `email`. That causes a bit of cognitive dissonance. Let's rename them `usererror`, `passworderror`, `verifyerror` and `emailerror`:

```
def reply(self, usererror, passworderror, verifyerror, emailerror):
```

Now to check that there are no errors use:

```
if not any(usererror and passworderror and verifyerror and emailerror):
```

But the page we want to redirect to needs the name of the user!
If we just redirect to `/broksi`:

```
        self.redirect('/broski')
```

then the `ThankYo` handler has no idea what the username is. `self.request.get('username')` would come up blank (return an empty string). So we need to pass along the username to `broski`:

```
import urllib

self.redirect('/broski?' + urllib.urlencode(
            {'username' : self.username}))
```

---

So the code ends up looking like this:

```
import urllib
import webapp2
import re
form = """<html>
<form method=post>
<input name="username"><div id=div>%s</div><br>
<input name="password"><div id=div>%s</div><br>
<input name="verify"><div id=div>%s</div><br>
<input name="email"><div id=div>%s</div>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</html>"""


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        self.response.write(form % ('', '', '', ''))

    def reply(self, usererror, passworderror, verifyerror, emailerror):
        if not any(usererror and passworderror and verifyerror and emailerror):
            self.redirect('/broski?' + urllib.urlencode(
                {'username' : self.username}))
        else:
            self.response.write(form % (user, password, verify, email))

    def post(self):
        self.username = self.request.get('username')
        self.password = self.request.get('password')
        self.verify = self.request.get('verify')
        self.email = self.request.get('email')
        self.usererror = ''
        if not re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,20}$").match(self.username):
            self.usererror = "That's not a valid username."
        self.passworderror = ''
        if not re.compile(r"^.{3,20}$").match(self.password):
            self.passworderror = "That wasn't a valid password."
        self.verifyerror = ''
        if self.verify != self.password and self.password != '':
            self.verifyerror = "Your passwords didn't match."
        self.emailerror = ''
        if not re.compile(r"^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$").match(self.email):
            self.emailerror = "That's not a valid email."
        self.reply(self.usererror, self.passworderror, self.verifyerror, self.emailerror)


class ThankYo(MainPage):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Welcome, ' + self.request.get('username') + '!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), ('/broski', ThankYo)],
                              debug=True)
```

Comment: I fixed that, instead had it inherit.Although one thing, how do you see the terminal? This is kind of silly, but i am new

Comment: Thanks, almost there. Everything else is working now only that when i submit valid details, it still just re-renders the form(I was hoping it would redirect to my fancy welcome page D:).

Comment: Update: I think i found the fatal mistake, i set it to != when it should be == -.-